# PHP include master page path issues

Tags: php, relative-path

I have a file structure like so:

```
Admin/index.php
index.php
master.php
site.js
```

Simplified version of `master.php`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="site.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $content ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Simplified version of `index.php`:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
Lorem ipsum
<?php
    $content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
    include("master.php");
?>
```

Simplified version of `Admin/index.php`:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
Lorem ipsum
<?php
    $content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
    include("../master.php");
?>
```

`index.php` works just fine, but in `Admin/index.php`, it tries to find `site.js` in the `Admin` folder...

I could use `/absolute/path/to/site.js`, but different instances of the site are running under different urls (such as `http://mysite.com/Instance1/Admin/index.php` etc...)

So how can I fix this so that it looks for `site.js` in the folder that `master.php` is in, and not the folder of page *including* `master.php`?

Comment: geez, why messy spaghetti code?! Use any sane templates engine, Luke.

Comment: Have you tried using a <base> tag in the head of your master.php file? Bear in mind it can be set dynamically if needed

Comment: try it by giving absolute path. by looking on your reputation, you better know how to give an absolute path :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 
`<base href="http:/site.com/" />`

put it in the head section of your HTML (between `<head> and </head>`).

The `<base>` tag specifies the base URL/target for all relative URLs in a document.

So if you set this to http://yoursite.com/instance1/ and you set your js to script.js it will fetch it from http://yoursite.com/instance1/script.js.